# Lifecycle Callbacks (PostConstruct, PreDestroy) in Reactive Spring

Tags: spring-webflux

I'd like to run some housekeeping tasks during startup and upon shutdown of my reactive Spring application. The most convenient way for me is to use the two lifecycle callback annotations `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy`:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DummyData {
    
    private final MyDataRepository myDataRepository;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        myDataRepository.initializeWithDummyData().block();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void cleanup() {
        myDataRepository.deleteAllData().block();
    }

}
```

I wonder now if there exists a cleaner solution (with or without annotations) that doesn't involve a `.block()` call?

Comment: i dont know the purpose as to why you want to initialize data on startup. I would suggest you to use the CommandRunner interface instead of using class lifecycle methods. Lifecycle methods are commonly use for class initialization, and not for side effects.

Comment: I think it's possible with several line of code. But it's still blocking because Spring Boot doesn't support reactive start up. So, the main part, you can simply create `ReactiveRunner` with one method (like `Publisher<?> run(...)`), autowire all subclasses and in `void run(...)` simply concat all results of method. It's still `block()` at the end, but all your start up logic can run in reactive style.